# file content get reduced when transfering to ftp server

Tags: java, binary-data, ftp-client

I wrote a java program  to recursively upload a directory to a remote ftp server using Apache.commons.net  library.By the program all files got uploaded to the remote ftp server as expected.but some html,js,svg,ftl file content getting reduced.Also some  jpeg,png,icon file sizes are different than original.I compare original directory and uploaded directory after uploading using meld software so that i can figure out that directory content got corrupted.I have tried both BINARY and ASCII transfer mode.both two modes getting same problem.so can any one suggest the reason why is this happening.Is this  a issue with ftp file transferring

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;




public class FtpClient3 {

public static boolean uploadSingleFile(FTPClient ftpClient,
                                       String localFilePath, String   remoteFilePath) throws IOException {
    File localFile = new File(localFilePath);

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);
    String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension(localFilePath);
    try {
        if(ext1== "ajx" || ext1== "am" || ext1=="asa" ||     ext1=="properties" || ext1=="asc" || ext1=="asp" || ext1=="aspx" || ext1=="awk"  || ext1=="bat" || ext1=="c" || ext1=="cdf" || ext1=="cf" || ext1=="cfg" || ext1=="cfm" || ext1=="cgi" || ext1=="cnf" || ext1=="conf" || ext1=="cpp" || ext1=="css" || ext1=="csv" || ext1=="ctl" || ext1=="dat" || ext1=="dhtml"|| ext1=="diz" || ext1=="file" || ext1=="forward" || ext1=="grp" || ext1=="h" || ext1=="hpp"|| ext1=="hqx" || ext1=="hta" || ext1=="htaccess" || ext1=="htc" || ext1=="htm" || ext1=="html" || ext1=="htpasswd" || ext1=="htt" || ext1=="htx"|| ext1=="in"|| ext1=="inc"|| ext1=="info"|| ext1=="ini"|| ext1=="ink"|| ext1=="java" || ext1=="js" || ext1=="jsp" || ext1=="log" || ext1=="logfile"|| ext1=="m3u"|| ext1=="m4a"|| ext1=="m4a"|| ext1=="mak"|| ext1=="map"|| ext1=="model"|| ext1=="msg"|| ext1=="nfo"|| ext1=="nsi" || ext1=="info"  || ext1=="old" || ext1=="pas" || ext1=="patch" || ext1=="perl" || ext1=="php"|| ext1=="php2"|| ext1=="php3" || ext1=="php4" || ext1=="php5" || ext1=="php6" || ext1=="phtml" || ext1=="pix" || ext1=="pl" || ext1=="pm" || ext1=="po"|| ext1=="pwd"|| ext1=="py" || ext1=="qmail" || ext1=="rb" || ext1=="rbl" || ext1=="rbw" || ext1=="readme" || ext1=="reg" || ext1=="rss" || ext1=="ruby" || ext1=="session" || ext1=="setup" || ext1=="sh" || ext1=="shtm"  || ext1=="shtml" || ext1=="sql" || ext1=="ssh" || ext1=="stm" || ext1=="style" || ext1=="svg" || ext1=="tcl" || ext1=="text" || ext1=="threads" || ext1=="tmpl" || ext1=="tpl" || ext1=="txt" || ext1=="ubb" || ext1=="vbs" || ext1=="xhtml" || ext1=="xml" || ext1=="xrc" || ext1=="xsl" || ext1=="rtf"){
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(ftpClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
            }
        else{
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(ftpClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        }


        return ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFilePath, inputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}







public static void uploadDirectory(FTPClient ftpClient,
                                   String remoteDirPath, String  localParentDir, String remoteParentDir)
        throws IOException {

    System.out.println("LISTING directory: " + localParentDir);

    File localDir = new File(localParentDir);
    File[] subFiles = localDir.listFiles();
    if (subFiles != null && subFiles.length > 0) {
        for (File item : subFiles) {
            String remoteFilePath = remoteDirPath + "/" + remoteParentDir
                    + "/" + item.getName();
            if (remoteParentDir.equals("")) {
                remoteFilePath = remoteDirPath + "/" + item.getName();
            }


            if (item.isFile()) {
                // upload the file
                String localFilePath = item.getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println("About to upload the file: " + localFilePath);
                //CHANGING
                boolean uploaded = uploadSingleFile(ftpClient,
                        localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
                if (uploaded) {
                    System.out.println("UPLOADED a file to: "
                            + remoteFilePath);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("COULD NOT upload the file: "
                            + localFilePath);
                }
            } else {
                // create directory on the server
                boolean created = ftpClient.makeDirectory(remoteFilePath);
                if (created) {
                    System.out.println("CREATED the directory: "
                            + remoteFilePath);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("COULD NOT create the directory: "
                            + remoteFilePath);
                }

                // upload the sub directory
                String parent = remoteParentDir + "/" + item.getName();
                if (remoteParentDir.equals("")) {
                    parent = item.getName();
                }

                localParentDir = item.getAbsolutePath();
                uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localParentDir,
                        parent);
            }
        }
    }
}






public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

    String server = "";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "";
    String pass = "";




    FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPClient();


   try {
        // connect and login to the server
        ftpclient.connect(server, port);
        ftpclient.login(user, pass);

        // use local passive mode to pass firewall
        ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        System.out.println("Connected");

        String remoteDirPath = "/dist";
        String localDirPath ="/data/IOT/ase-core";


        FtpClient3.uploadDirectory(ftpclient, remoteDirPath, localDirPath, "");

        // log out and disconnect from the server
        ftpclient.logout();
        ftpclient.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Disconnected");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

}

Comment: Are you transferring in binary mode? Once by mistake I transferred in ASCII mode and it broke every single file. You should post the code you use to upload files to the server

Comment: To answer your update: No, this is not an issue with FTP file transferring. Again, post your code.

Comment: yes  first i tried with binary mode but file content getting reduced so i decided to  change the mode according to file type.that set the mode of text files to ASCII and other image files such as JPEG,PNG to binary mode but same problem comming again

Comment: It's an issue with your code. Include it in the question, otherwise we'll not be able to help you

Comment: yes i included it

Comment: You call `upfile()` in `uploadDirectory` but you don't show the code. You only show `uploadSingleFile()` which is not used.

Comment: its a mistake upfile()   should be  uploadSingleFile()  . initially  that was  uploadSingleFile() later i changed that to  upfile() for test with another method and forget to change it .now i corrected  it in my code.even if that was changed  the above problem is happening can u find any mistakes in my code other than it

Comment: Just to check if it's a problem with the FTP server configuration, do you also get these problems if you use third-party FTP client software?

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say that the uploaded files are corrupted, have you tried to download the files from the server using a third party software (i.e. filezilla) and you find them corrupted?

Comment: yes that  is how i verified the file is corrupted even if i upload the directory using filezilla directly and download it again and check with original again same problem happening that is files  got corrupted

Comment: @Mufarrij so the problem is in the server.

Comment: how u telling  that the problem is in the server

Comment: @Mufarrij because i find very improbable that there is an upload error in filezilla. If both your upload and filezilla upload fails then look at the server side.

Comment: yes but  here we are uploading  around  160 files to the server and  there only  around  10 to 15 files are getting corrupted including both text and binary files.for  small directories  the code is  working correctly.so i think there is less chance of it could be a server issue